# What should I do with tag, which is used for different types of questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

Some tags have different meanings and are used for different types of questions.

I found that, when I wanted to write a description for an [education](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education) tag.

As I saw, it's used for:

- Marking questions about project management within the education area.

  (Example: [Can Scrum be effectively applied to a PhD research project?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/15402/can-scrum-be-effectively-applied-to-a-phd-research-project))
- Marking questions related to education (courses, high education and others) in the project management area.

  (Example: [Is there a difference between the PMP and the CAPM in terms of what to study?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/2528/is-there-a-difference-between-the-pmp-and-the-capm-in-terms-of-what-to-study))

So, I see two possible solutions:

- Write in a tag's description, that it may be used for marking two different types of questions.
- Make another tag for one type of question and remark all related questions.

Which of them is better? Or, maybe, there exists some other way to solve this problem?

Comment: The best approach is for tags to be focused so they serve their intended purpose, for grouping related information.  You might propose a separate tag, or perhaps we remove the tag completely if other tags already accurately categorize these two questions.

Answer (score 1):

The tag current says:

> The education tag has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?

In cases like this, I'd say that the first question is mistagged because it isn't about PM-related education (which is likely to be the intent of the tag). Other questions are getting lumped in, too, such as questions about educating clients/stakeholders.

There are currently only 19 questions tagged with [education](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education), so the community should take one or more of the following steps:

1. Update the tag guidance.
2. Create tags that are more specific or more useful, if needed.
3. Remove the tag from questions where it no longer fits.
4. Retag the questions appropriately.

It could very well be that [education](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education) is too meta, and that we should simply attempt to remove it from all questions. I'll leave it to someone else to ponder whether the tag is useful or worth salvaging.